# Print solo keys, sin values que no son dicts. Python

Tags: python

Quiero realizar un print del json pero solo de todas las keys que tenga el dic.
Lo necesito porque se me dificulta mucho leerlo en la consola si me muestra todas las values que no son dic.
El resultado esperado sería algo asi:

```
{
    'bozo': '',
    'encoding': '',
    'entries': [],
    'feed': {
        'link': '',
        'links': [
            {
                'href': '',
                'rel': '',
                'type': ''
            }
        ],
        'subtitle': '',
        'subtitle_detail': {
            'base': '',
            'language': '',
            'type': '',
            'value': ''
        },
        'title': '',
        'title_detail': {
            'base': '',
            'language': '',
            'type': '',
            'value': ''
        }
    },
    'namespaces': {},
    'version': ''
}
```

Code:

```
import json

user_detail = {'bozo': 'Esteban', 'encoding': 'utf', 'entries': [], 'feed': {'link': 'www.martin.com', 'links': [{'href': '--', 'rel': '--', 'type': '--'}], 'subtitle': '--', 'subtitle_detail': {'base': '--', 'language': '--', 'type': '--', 'value': '--'}, 'title': '--', 'title_detail': {'base': '', 'language': '--', 'type': '--', 'value': '--'}}, 'namespaces': {}, 'version': '--'}


def def_user_info():
    print(json.dumps(user_detail, indent=4))


def_user_info()
```

Comment: ¿También las claves de los diccionarios anidados o solo las del principal?

Comment: de los anidados tambien y que lo haga con un indent=4, para poder identificar de que key proviene digamos... me explico?

Comment: Si, igual que formatea json.dumps pero sin los valores de las claves.

Comment: Exatamente, pero siempre y cuando los "valores" no sean keys digamos...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otra versión recursiva en la que las claves de los diccionarios anidados dentro de una lista se delimitan usando `{}` y además se puede definir la identificación que se desea utilizar:

```
def def_user_info(data, indent=4):
    def parser(data, _indent=0, _li=False):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            if _li:
                print(f"{' ' * (_indent - indent)}{{")
            for key, value in data.items():
                if isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
                    print(f"{' ' * _indent}{key}")
                    parser(value, _indent=_indent + indent, _li=False)
                else:
                    print(f"{' ' * _indent}{key}")
            if _li:
                print(f"{' ' * (_indent - indent)}}}")
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            for item in data:
                if isinstance(item, (dict, list)):
                    parser(item, _indent=_indent + indent, _li=True)
    parser(data, _li=isinstance(data, list))
```

> ```
> >>> def_user_info(user_detail, 4)
>
> bozo
> encoding
> entries
> feed
>     link
>     links
>         {
>             href
>             rel
>             type
>         }
>     subtitle
>     subtitle_detail
>         base
>         language
>         type
>         value
>     title
>     title_detail
>         base
>         language
>         type
>         value
> namespaces
> version
> ```

Otro ejemplo con más de un diccionario anidado dentro de una lista:

> ```
> user_detail = {"foo": [
>                   {
>                       "aaa": 1,
>                       "bbb": 2
>                   },
>                   {   "kkk": 4,
>                       "jjj": 8}
>                ],
>                "bar": {
>                    "fff": 7,
>                    "ttt": 3
>                 }
>               }
>
> >>> def_user_info(user_detail, 4)
>
> foo
>     {
>         aaa
>         bbb
>     }
>     {
>         kkk
>         jjj
>     }
> bar
>     fff
>     ttt
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacerlo con una simple función recursiva:

```
def print_keys(d, level=0, indent=4):
  for k,v in d.items():
    print("{}{}".format(" "*level*indent, k))
    if type(v)==dict:
      print_keys(v, level+1)
```

Ejemplo de datos y resultado:

```
data = {
    'bozo': '',
    'encoding': '',
    'entries': [],
    'feed': {
        'link': '',
        'links': [
            {
                'href': '',
                'rel': '',
                'type': ''
            }
        ],
        'subtitle': '',
        'subtitle_detail': {
            'base': '',
            'language': '',
            'type': '',
            'value': ''
        },
        'title': '',
        'title_detail': {
            'base': '',
            'language': '',
            'type': '',
            'value': ''
        }
    },
    'namespaces': {},
    'version': ''
}
print_keys(data)
```

---

```
bozo
encoding
entries
feed
    link
    links
    subtitle
    subtitle_detail
        base
        language
        type
        value
    title
    title_detail
        base
        language
        type
        value
namespaces
version
```

**Nota**. Observa que si uno de los valores es una lista, como el caso `links`, no "desciende" más por ese lado. No tengo claro si es esto lo que deseas.

Si necesitas que itere por esa lista y vuelque también los diccionarios de las claves que obtenga, eso se conseguirá con la siguiente variante:

```
def print_keys(d, level=0, indent=4):
  for k,v in d.items():
    print("{}{}".format(" "*level*indent, k))
    if type(v)==dict:
      print_keys(v, level+1, indent)
    elif type(v)==list:
      for elem in v:
        if type(elem) == dict:
          print_keys(elem, level+1, indent)
```

Sin embargo tengo mis dudas sobre si la salida sería útil en esta forma.

Si la lista (por ejemplo `links`) tiene varios elementos, aparecerían las claves de todos ellos, una tras otra, sin poder diferenciar a qué elemento pertenece cada clave. Si intentamos separarlos de algún modo (por ejemplo, poniendo un "-" cada vez que empieza un elemento nuevo), podemos encontrar el problema de que la lista no tenga diccionarios, y entonces esos "separadores" quedarían mal. Es posible incluso que todos los elementos de la lista tengan siempre las mismas claves, y que no te interese verlas repetidas, sino sólo un "resumen" de qué claves comparten todos ellos...

Comment: links necesito que si descienda porque tiene dicts dentro de esa lista, lo demás esta perfecto!!

Answer (score 3):

Una forma alternativa, y te diría, no la más natural, pero que puede tener alguna utilidad en el algún caso, es trabajar sobre la cadena y usar expresiones regulares:

```
import re

matches = re.finditer(r"\"(\w+)\":", json.dumps(user_detail))
for match in matches:
    print(match.group(1))
```

El patrón, busca capturar las expresiones de una cadena que sean las `keys` de un diccionario, es decir un patrón como este: `"clave":`. Luego simplemente iteramos con cada ocurrencia y con `match.group(1)` obtenemos la clave capturada.

Answer (score 1):

Algo asi estas buscando?

De esta manera se puede loopear los `dict`:  `key` y `value` , en este caso solo interesa `key`

```
for key, value in user_detail.items(): 
    print(key)
```

output

```
bozo
encoding
entries
feed
namespaces
version
```

Esta manera 'chancha' puede ser una opción para mostrar todos las `keys`, ya que en algunos `value` de `user_detail`, se pueden apreciar anidados.

```
for key, value in user_detail.items(): 
    print(key)
    if type(value) == dict:
        for xkey, xvalue in value.items():
            print(xkey)
```

output

```
bozo
encoding
entries
feed
link
links
subtitle
subtitle_detail
title
title_detail
namespaces
version
```

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación de cómo esto soluciona el problema dwl OP

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, el problema es que al no saber cuan anidado es el dic, deberia crear un loop por cada value que sea un dic. Necesito que eso lko haga de forma automatica digamos..