# Recorrer diccionarios y formar una jerarquía

Tags: python, django

Quiero recorrer el siguiente diccionario, que a su vez contiene otro diccionario y asi repetitivamente:

```
datos = {'Elen SanzE': {
    'Ester rodriguez': {'Fernando Morales': {}, 'Victor Gordaliza': {}, 'Alberto Pareja': {}, 'Henar Salas': {},
                         'Elias Lopez': {}, 'Marcos Lopez': {}, 'Belen Gomez': {}, 'Virginia Sanchez': {},
                         'Jose Manuel TIrado': {}, 'Antonio Manrique': {}},
    'Pedro Ramirez': {}}}
```

Y me gustaria que se viera por pantalla como si fuera una jerarquia formada por tabulaciones, vertical u horizontal o de otra forma.

He conseguido imprimir el diccionario completo con recursividad de forma lineal, pero no consigo hacer lo de la jerarquia:

```
def recorrer(diccionario):
    for h, k in diccionario.items():
        print(h)
        if type(k) is not None:
            recorrer(diccionario[h])

recorrer(datos)
```

[image: Imagen de muestra]

Me gustaria que saliera del estilo de la imagen, si se os ocurre alguna manera gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manteniendo la formula que has hecho, te valdría algo así?

```
def recorrer(diccionario, espacio=0):

    for h, k in diccionario.items():
        print(' ' * espacio, h)
        if type(k) is not None:
            recorrer(diccionario[h], espacio + 2)

recorrer(datos)
```

Ahora mismo añade 2 espacios en cada jerarquía, empezando desde 0 y se ve como el resultado que has pedido.

Si lo único que quieres es ver la jerarquía, también puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
import json

print(json.dumps(datos, indent=4))
```

Con esto no necesitas la función 'recorrer', y te mostraría el resultado así:

```
{
    "Elen SanzE": {
        "Ester rodriguez": {
            "Fernando Morales": {},
            "Victor Gordaliza": {},
            "Alberto Pareja": {},
            "Henar Salas": {},
            "Elias Lopez": {},
            "Marcos Lopez": {},
            "Belen Gomez": {},
            "Virginia Sanchez": {},
            "Jose Manuel TIrado": {},
            "Antonio Manrique": {}
        },
        "Pedro Ramirez": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me valen las dos formas.

Comment: Fijate si te sirven las respuestas que dieron en esta publicación.   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283082/print-solo-keys-sin-values-que-no-son-dicts-python/ , para completar los ejemplos